# What is easy way to convert object in array Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application was built on Angular JS and has a lot AJAX requests on server.
For example, in PHP I format output **array** like as:

```
$dialog[$userId] = array(
   'time' => $key,
   'message' => $message['message'],
   'name_user'  => $info['name']
);

echo json_encode($dialog); die();
```

But in Angular JS I get not array but object:

> 549: Objectid_user: "549"message: "Hello"name_user: "Ali
>   Akhmedov"time: 1432070505

Problem that if use `ng-repeat` then does not work sorting for object.
Why in PHP I set array but on client get object?

What easy way to convert object to array? Because I have a lot objects on page from AJAX.

Comment: json_encode parses associate arrays in php as objects in json.

Comment: Associative arrays **are** (JS-)objects. It's not clear what kind of data you want, are you happy with `[1432070505, "Hello", "Ali Akhmedo"]`?

Comment: Okay, what is way to resolve problem?

Comment: I want that work orderBy in `ng-repeat` for object with key: `549: Objectid_user: "549"message: "Hello"name_user: "Ali Akhmedov"time: 1432070505`

Comment: @vaved That depends on what exactly what you need to achieve ?

Comment: @vaved In PHP, make sure you have only numeric keys in `$dialog`, and every key between `0` and the highest id is set, then `json_encode` will output an array.

Comment: Do you mean to do `$dialog[] = array()`?

Comment: Depends. Will every response contain all records? Does the index matter?

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to convert object to array in order to iterate over it in `ng-repeat`. You can just use the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{key}} => {{value}}</div>
```

[Documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) of `ngRepeat`.

Unfortunately, this approach will not work with `orderBy` filter. To iterate over object properties in specific order, you need to implement your own filter. It may be something like that:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  filter('orderByKey', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(items, field, reverse) {
      var keys = $filter('orderBy')(Object.keys(items), field, reverse),
          obj = {};
      keys.forEach(function(key) {
        obj[key] = items[key];
      });
      return obj;
    };
  }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items | orderByKey:'-'">{{key}} => {{value}}</div>
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/DJo0Y6GaOzSuoi202Hkj?p=preview

However even this approach will work only starting from `1.4.x`, since as it is stated in documentation, AngularJS prior to `1.4.x` will sort object properties in alphabetic order while iterating over them in `ngRepeat`.

In order to make it work in Angular `1.3.x` or even `1.2.x` you may perform conversion of object to array of objects, each one of which will contain `key` and `value` properties. That way you will be able to use it in `ngRepeat` in combination with filters including `orderBy`. Here is a code:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  factory('srv', ['$http', function($http) {
    var items = [],
        loaded = false;
    return {
      getItems: function() {
        if(!loaded) { // Lazy loading
          $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) { // {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
              items.push({key: key, value: data[key]});
            });
          });
          loaded = true;
        }
        return items; // [{key: 'key1', value:'val1'}, {key:'key2', value: 'val2'}]
      }
    };
  }]).
  controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'srv', function($scope, srv) {
    $scope.items = srv.getItems();
  }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'-key'">{{item.key}} => {{item.value}}</div>
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/UXmlm1GKYRZzrOV5pMYT?p=preview

Comment: But if I want to show data sorted from latest to oldest? I tried `-key` and  `+key` have not difference. Des not work

Comment: @vaved I updated the answer with two additional solutions for angular 1.4.x and earlier versions. Please take a look, it works with filters as well.

Comment: This works, but isn't this technically not valid because it relies on JavaScript maintaining the insertion order of object properties, which is not guaranteed?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have an object like:

```
$scope.myObj = {type:"Fiat", model:500, color:"white"};
```

Then, in your angular `Controller` you can do something like:

```
$scope.array = [];
angular.forEach($scope.myObj, function(element) {
  $scope.array.push(element);
});
```

and then in your `HTML`

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in array">{{obj}}</div>
```

Here is a demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yp5Z9WotKlxS8hnjGc8P?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

`orderBy` is a filter, and filters [require an array](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray). So a straightforward solution is to combine it with a `toArray` filter. Supposing you want to order your objects using their `time` property:

```
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="value in objectWithValues | toArray | orderBy: 'time'">
    {{value.name_user}} said <q>{{value.message}}</q> on {{value.time|date}}
  </li>
</ol>
```

As the `toArray` filter is not shipped with AngularJS, you can define one as:

```
angular.module('ToArrayDemo', [])
  .filter('toArray', function() {
    return function(obj) {
      const result = [];
      angular.forEach(obj, function(val) {
        result.push(val);
      });
     return result;
   }
 });
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/E857InfrEGqToW0SvwOh?p=preview